# Windows Forms and Exceptionless Report

Tags: winforms, exceptionless

I have started using exceptionless for a windows forms application.  Whenever it notices that the program is crashed it throws up this window:

[image: Exceptionless Error Report Window]

I really do not want it to do this, as I want it to submit the errors to me, with out a user being able to stop it.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Seems a bit evil not to give users the option on whether data is transmitted to a remote server

Comment: Its actually an internal program, going to a self hosted server, so not giving them the option isn't that evil ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find it :)

```cs
ExceptionlessClient.Default.Register(showDialog: false);
```

> showDialog: Controls whether a dialog is shown when an unhandled exception occurs.